# Proving a generalization of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, conformal-geometry, entire-functions

> Suppose $w = f(z), \space z \in \mathbb{C} \space$ is an entire function which fails to take any values belonging to some curve $\gamma$ in the $w$-plane. Show that $f(z)$ is constant.

This problem appears in my textbook "Complex Analysis with Applications" by Silverman. I'm having a very tough time interpreting this question, let alone beginning to prove it.

What do they mean when they say "$f$ fails to take any values belonging to $\gamma$ in the $w$-plane?" This sentence does not make sense to me. It sounds like they are saying the domain of $f$ does not include points in $\gamma$, but $f$ is entire, so that cannot be. Do they mean that the image of $f$ does not contain the curve $\gamma$?

They gave a hint to consider the function $g(z) = \phi(f(z)), \space z \in \mathbb{C}$, where $\phi: \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P} \setminus \gamma  \to \mathbb{D}_1(0)$ maps the extended complex plane with boundary $\gamma$ to the unit disk.

However, I don't know where to begin using this hint. Riemann Mapping Theorem tells us that for any *simply connected* domain $G$ in the extended plane whose boundary contains more than one point in $G$, there exists a unique univalent function $w = f(z)$ which maps $G$ conformally onto the unit disk.

As far as I can tell, $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P} \setminus \gamma$ is not simply connected, so I see no reason why the $\phi$ defined above need be univalent (or even exist). Nor do I see how such a fact would help me if it was. Clearly, the fact that $f$ is entire needs to enter somewhere, but where?

Comment: I read it as follows: $A=\gamma([0,1])$ where $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ is continuous and nonconstant, and $f(\Bbb C)\subseteq \Bbb C\setminus A$.

Comment: The image of $f$ is disjoint from the image of gamma. That is, we have a curve $\gamma\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ and an entire function $f\colon \Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, and we are given that $\forall z\in\Bbb C\,\forall t\in \Bbb R\colon f(z)\ne \gamma(t)$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Okay, that is what I was thinking, thank you. This means that $g$ defined above maps the (extended) complex plane to the unit disk. It seems to me that *if* $f$ we constant, then $g$ would have to be as well. Similarly, if I could say that $\phi$ were univalent (or at least non-constant), and  $g$ were constant, $f$ must be as well. Are there any properties I utilize to make this happen? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $\Bbb C\Bbb P\setminus \gamma$ need not be simply connected - or even connected.
But only one of its connected components, $U_0$ say, contains the image of $f$. The complement of $U_0$ is connected because each of the connected components of $\Bbb C\Bbb P\setminus \gamma$  touches $\gamma$. We conclude that $U_0$ is simply connected and can be Riemann-mapped to the unit disk.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thank you! So (if I'm following correctly) this allows us to construct such a univalent function $\phi$ defined in the hint (or perhaps just one mapping $U_0$ to the unit disk, but this shouldn't cause trouble). Now to prove the claim, I can see that, since $\phi$ is univalent, $g(z) = \phi(f(z))$ is constant if and only if $f$ is constant. Moreover, $g$ maps the (extended) complex plane to the unit disk. Can I conclude that $g$ is constant from here, or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Furthermore, $g$ is clearly bounded since $|g(z)| < 1$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If $g$ were entire, then Liouville theorem would give us that $f$ is constant. Can I say $g$ is entire?